# how to stop password popups

Tags: macos, password

I have a new macbook with osx 10.8.2

Every time I want do delete a file, open a downloaded file, and numerous other actions I have to enter my password. Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: Possible related: [Why does OS X Lion ask for my password whenever I delete a file in my home directory?](http://superuser.com/questions/313845/why-does-os-x-lion-ask-for-my-password-whenever-i-delete-a-file-in-my-home-direc)

Comment: veltar, can you try the solutions listed in the question linked by @josso and report back whether your problem is solved or not?

Answer (score -2):

That sounds odd, have you tried repairing permissions on Disk Utility? I assume you're the only owner of that macbook.

Anyhow when you try to delete a critical file it will prompt you for your password.

You can also enable the root user:

> sudo passwd root

If you log in as root it won't prompt you anymore but this will give access to any application to your system. This way you'll be vulnerable to all kind of malware including trojans.

Comment: I really wouldn't advice anyone to log in and work as the root user.